# Angular UI router how can I redirect a deep link?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to Angular UI router and am trying to understand how I can prevent users from using a saved hyperlink to jump into the middle of my app. I always want all favorites or otherwise memorized links to be forced to run the code runs when they initially come to the site. However, I don't want to prevent the user from reaching the state if they get to it via the apps menus and tabs.

Code-wise what I want to do is force a link to "/feature1/subfeature1" to "/" in the state tree below, but only if the link is from some link the user memorized.

```
$stateProvider
.state('main', {
  url: "/",
  templateUrl: "partials/main.html"
})
.state('feature1', {
  url: "/feature1",
  templateUrl: "partials/feature1.html"
})
.state('feature1.subfeature1', {
  url: "/feature1/subfeature1",
  templateUrl: "partials/feature1.subfeature1.html",
  controller: ......
  }
})
```

The Angular UI Router FAQ had section on preventing a user from reaching a state, but when I ran a sample the event handler is invoked for all stateChangeStart events, including legitimate navigation within the app via $state.go(). I was hoping to differentiate between detect hyperlinks that jump into the middle of the app and $state.go(), since I only use $state.go() to navigate states.  Code-wise I think want to do something like the code below.  But, don't know what code goes into the "NEED TEST HERE".

```
 app.run(function($rootScope, $state,) {
   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, to) {

    var isDeepLink =  NEED TEST HERE 

    if (isDeepLink ) {
      e.preventDefault();
    // Optionally set option.notify to false if you don't want 
    // to retrigger another $stateChangeStart event
     $state.go("\");
    }
}
});
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Jerry

Answer (score 0):

How about create a service that registers whether or not the application has initialized.  In this example, I define "app has initialized" as "the root state's controller has been invoked".

```
app.service("appInit", function() { 
    var done = false;
    return { 
        isDone: function() { return isinitialized; },  
        initDone: function() { isinitialized = true; }
    }
}
```

---

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state, appInit) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, to) {
  if (!appInit.isDone()) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Optionally set option.notify to false if you don't want 
    // to retrigger another $stateChangeStart event
    $state.go("\");
  }
}
```

---

```
$stateProvider
.state('main', {
  url: "/",
  templateUrl: "partials/main.html",
  controller: function(appInit) { appInit.initDone(); }
})
```

---

## Edit: a much simpler solution:

This simpler solution works because the only time the transition is from the root state ("") is during the initial transition when the app is first loading.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state, appInit) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, to, toParams, from) {
  if (from.name === "" && to.name !=== "main") {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Optionally set option.notify to false if you don't want 
    // to retrigger another $stateChangeStart event
    $state.go("\");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have it backwards, `$stateChangeStart` will always fire **except** when it's a Deep Link.

Therefore, this code will do what you ask,

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state,) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, to) {
     // code here runs if it is not a deep link
  });
  // code here runs if its a deep link
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not seem to be the case.  I see the code fire the $stateChangeStart event when I click on a favorite link.